# set theory with only countable sets

Tags: set-theory

I want to ask something simple: Is there a formulation of set theory where only countable sets are allowed? Meaning that for every set S there is a surjection from the naturals to S.

Comment: I think you can get what you are looking for from Zermelo set theory (ZF without replacement) by restricting the axiom of power sets to finite sets. I don't know of any work on such a system.

Comment: If you'd like to keep the empty set, then I think you should also say $S$ is non-empty, or talk about injections going the other way. Could you perhaps explain a little more about what you are interested in here? Most usual notions of "set theory" will prove the existence of uncountable sets (as viewed from inside the theory, anyway).

Comment: Yeah you are right about that detail. I guess what i'm trying to say is that I want a formulation of set theory that doesn't create uncountable sets, meaning that the set of natural numbers is the biggest set you could have.